# Css выпадающий список

Tags: css

надо с помощью только css сделать выпадающий список
каждый пункт меню в себе имеет еще несколько (первый например 2 , а второй 3)
как сделать так , чтобы высота пункта при наведении увеличивалась в 2 или в 3 раза в зависимости от пункта. Только средствами css это возможно??

Comment: nth-child ?

Comment: На чистом CSS вряд ли получится, JS скорее всего потребуется.

Comment: Подпункты куда при этом должны деться? Можно ими и раздвигать, хотя в люббом случае велосипед безобразия получится.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял Вас, то это поможет:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Frontend Development</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Resets</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Grids</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Frameworks</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Ajax</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Backend Dev</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Ruby</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Ruby on Rails</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sinatra</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">PHP</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">WordPress</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Symfony</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><p>From Russia with <span class="fa fa-heart"</span></p></li>
</ul>
```

**SCSS**

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #1bc2a2;

  li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    background: #1bc2a2;

    ul { 
      display: none; 

      li { border-top: 0; }
    }

    a {
      display: block;
      padding: 1em;
      text-decoration: none;
      white-space: nowrap;
      color: white;

      &:hover { background: #2c3e50; }
    }

    p {
      color: white;
      padding-left: 1em;

      & span {
        color: red;
      }
    }
  }
}

li:hover {

  > ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
  }

  li {
    float: none;

    & a:hover { background: #2c3e50; }
  }

  a { background: #1bc2a2; }
}

ul ul ul {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

// Clearfix 

ul {

  &:before, &:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
  }

  &:after { clear: both; }
}
```

Поиграться на CodePen можно [здесь](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOKZEV).

Comment: Хотя, конечно же, лучше это всё сделать с помощью JS/jQuery.